# Как получить координаты курсора в окне curses?

Tags: ncurses, curses

Нужно получить текущие координаты `y x` курсора в стандартном окне `curses` (`ncurses`), но никак не могу найти подходящую функцию. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужный макрос уже найден: это

```
getsyx(curscr, y, x);
```

Для тех кому это будет полезно. Кстати, перед `y x` не нужно ставить `&`, так как это макрос, а не функция. Этим значениям будут присвоены координаты текущей позиции курсора.